# Can we execute make from an android app's internal storage?

Tags: android, shell, makefile

I'm trying to run a makefile from the app's internal storage (`/data/data/%package%/..)`. The makefile is triggered by a run.sh file stored in the application-specific folder in the internal storage.

The Shell script

```
06-24 17:14:16.893 E/File Manager: Shell: #!/system/bin/sh 
06-24 17:14:16.893 E/File Manager: Shell: /data/data/com.mkmv.playground/files/appfldr/make -f /data/data/com.mkmv.playground/files/appfldr/tmp/Makefile
```

And the Log

```
06-24 17:14:16.956 E/File Manager: Execution Error: /system/bin/sh: sed: not found
                                   /system/bin/sh: sed: not found
                                   /system/bin/sh: sed: not found
                                   /system/bin/sh: sed: not found
                                   /system/bin/sh: sed: not found
```

Ran `chmod 777` on all files in the `appfldr`, only to end in vain.

Also, tried adding

```
"cd " + this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/appfldr \n";
```

to the shell script, before executing the makefile, nothing happens.

**When I tried running the same on a rooted phone, it works just fine both with and without `cd` ing even without asking for superuser access. But in an unrooted device it doesn't. As far as I researched on the topic, the application should be able to execute from its private folder. Where am I wrong?**

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need a rooted device. The Android OS may block some commands on unrooted devices

Comment: But when I tried on a rooted device, superuser never requested root access. Even when I checked the superuser log, nothing relating the application was found there!

Comment: There is still a difference between rooted Android and non-rooted Android. Even if you don't request superuser access, there is still a difference.

Comment: We'll, do you have any idea about changing the pwd to appfldr from within the app. Why is that not allowed?

Comment: For the answer to that question, ask google (or frequent modifiers of the AOSP)

Answer (score 0):

At last, answering my own question.

My unfamiliarity with terminal is the main issue. **The problem was `sed` was not available.** As I guessed, the application had no issue accessing the internal directory. In the rooted device, busybox had `sed` added to the `$PATH` and hence it worked fine. Managed to add `sed` in the unrooted device also and things work just as desired!

Thank you, whoever attempted to help me!